# Get the current time and date by using DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: php

How can I get the current date and time for this time zone 'America/phoenix'? I can't figure out how this can be done with the DateTime::createFromFormat.

My Code example

```
<?php

$format = 'n-j-Y g:iA';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '/*Example: 6-12-2019 12:05am*/', new 
DateTimeZone('America/phoenix'));
echo $date->format('n-j-Y g:iA') . "\n";

?>
```

Comment: what problem/error you get in your code? seems like working fine:- https://3v4l.org/dovnf

Comment: I updated my answer, it does what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the second parameter of `createFromFormat`, but from your question, I guess you are not America/phoenix, therefore, use this code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/phoenix');
$currentTimeInPhoenix = date('n-j-Y g:iA');//gets the currenttime in phoenix
$format = 'n-j-Y g:iA';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $currentTimeInPhoenix, new DateTimeZone('America/phoenix'));
echo $date->format('n-j-Y g:iA') . "\n";
date_default_timezone_set('YOUR OLD TIMEZONE');
?>
```

Comment: Why do you include stuff in your question that does not belong there?

Comment: You made us all confused, I updated my answer, please post exactly what you need, so we can help you better

Comment: I'm sorry every one for the confusion i'm just very tired right now I can't think straight and OMG @RayA that's what I wanted thank you :) I can now go to bed now ha ha ha.